# Sqlite уникальное сочетание столбцов

Tags: sqlite

Возможно ли такое в базах данных,что два и более столбцов уникальны только вместе?

```
projNr   jahr  Bezeich
K0XXX     2015  Berlin
K0XXX     2015  London
K0121     2015  ...
```

Например, чтобы попытка добавить строку       `K0XXX   2015  Berlin` 
не увенчались успехом.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Разумеется, такое возможно. Это называется "составной ключ", обычно речь идет о составном первичном ключе.

Составной первичный ключ создается вместе с таблицей так:

```
create table TheTable (
    a, b, c,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
)
```

Дополнительный ключ, он же ограничение уникальности, задается так:

```
create table TheTable (
    a, b, c,
    CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (a, b)
)
```

Разница между первичным ключом и дополнительным ключом - в том, что первичный ключ может быть только один и не может содержать необязательные атрибуты (указанные в нем атрибуты автоматически получают модификатор NOT NULL).

Также ограничение уникальности можно наложить при помощи уникального индекса:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_TheTable ON TheTable (a, b)
```

Разница между уникальным индексом и дополнительным ключом - в семантике. Ограничение уникальности - это часть модели данных, уникальный же индекс - это способ оптимизации поиска в БД. Но реально во всех известным мне реализациях они, как правило, взаимозаменяемы.

Еще одна возможность индекса, которой нет у ограничений - частичные индексы:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_TheTable ON TheTable (a, b) WHERE c <> 4
```

Теперь если атрибут `c` равен 4, то значения пары атрибутов `(a, b)` могут повторяться. Не знаю, правда, зачем такое может потребоваться...

PS отвечал я, в основном, про SQLite - но и для других СУБД многое из этого ответа применимо, поскольку "вырастает" из теории реляционных баз данных и из стандарта языка SQL.